# A 'no symbol' appears after clicking add comment button

Tags: bug, comments

When you click the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button, a [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) symbol appears.

Demonstration:

[image: demonstration for Arqade]

This was tested and reproduced on Arqade, RPi.SE and Meta.SE

Comment: And? Once you click, the button turns *inactive*, with an accompanying "no symbol" on mouse-over. This is new, and I don't think really a bug. It is localized to the *inactive* button(s); you'll see the same with other buttons as well.